# Generate list of route URLs on application start and insert into javascript file in MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, global-variables

My application makes many of its calls to Action methods using AJAX calls from my javascript(using `$.get`, `$.post`, etc.)

I am trying to clean up my javascript files now and the only thing preventing me from completely removing inline script from a page is the need to have my action method routes render in page so I can set them to the correct variables for my javascript.

Example being something like

```
url = '@Url.Action("SomeMethod","SomeController",new{area="SomeArea"})'
```

What I would like to do is have a method run in `global.asax` that generates the routes I need(I don't have a problem programming them by hand) and then checks them against a file`app.js`-- which includes all the generated urls hardcoded -- and changes a url if neseccary.

This way I can have all my urls in my global object without having to use inline script to render the urls. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So after doing more research I've come across a solution appropriate for what I want:

1. Create an `ActionResult` method that returns a partial view that is basically `app.js` inline.

   - Or write the javascript directly in the controller method and return `JavasScriptResult` , [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778069/1469797) -- though this is frowned upon.
2. Create an `ActionFilterAttribute` that sets caching for the above method, [per these instructions](http://thomasardal.com/yslow-rule-3-add-an-expires-or-a-cache-control-header/).
3. Include a `<script>` tag in the `<head>` whose source points to the javascript actionresult method.

So the end result:

```
public JavaScriptResult GetApp()
{
 return PartialView("App.js.cshtml");
}
```

Set the caching properties to once every 24 hours(or whatever) so that my call to the controller is only hit once. Now I can ensure changed urls are propagated to the client without using inline rendering.