# Asp.Net, Request and response

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A bit of a newbie question but I am confused here.

I understand how post/get requests works.

I am trying to understand this code for `test.aspx`:

```
....
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
Response.Write("function submitForm()");
Response.Write("{");
Response.Write("document.form4.submit();");
Response.Write("}");
Response.Write("submitForm();");
Response.Write("</script>");
```

Where `form4` is a form thats action is a post call to some webservice(testWebservice).

So I am a bit confused, If i call test.aspx the response I should get is the response from the webservice testWebservice ?

Sorry if i am not clear enough let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This writes a piece of javascript to the response stream, making it execute on the client when called. In this case it submits a form, resulting in calling a web service and returning its answer.

This is the same as you would return a JavaScriptResult, but is considered bad practice  because you mix UI and controller logic (see [Working example for JavaScriptResult in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677325/working-example-for-javascriptresult-in-asp-net-mvc)).

In other words, try to avoid this.