# Only calling action through Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

Based on this question ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670415/mvc-how-to-return-instruction-to-run-javascipt-method/1670447#1670447)) I want to know if is good to have a mvc application just using ajax call?

Thanks,
Pedro

Comment: You can handle Ajax requests with controllers just as you would any other request in a MVC application.

Comment: i know i can, but my question is, is it good or wrong? please suggestions. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context. Here are some pros and cons

Pros:

- An application which has multiple sections which need to be updated independently will be easier to write using ajax calls because you don't need to maintain the state of each section over postback.
- Smaller web requests -> better performance
- No need to maintain scrolled position of window, a full postback would otherwise scroll to the top of the page

Cons:

- Difficult to design so that its current state can be bookmarked
- Not navigatable by search engines
- Back/forward buttons don't work without quite a bit of effort
- Requires javascript to be enabled

Martin

Comment: +1 I was about to hit submit with my answer when yours popped up and it was near identical.  You win.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your project.

There is no good or bad approach here, but you must remember users that does not have JS enabled. If you depend on ajax for all the app interactions then you must do a separate behaviour for those users that does not use JS (browser JS not enabled).

That always lead to something like this at controller level:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                //Ajax Request
                //Return partial mostly for partial refresh of the page
                return View("PartialView");
            }

            //Regular Request
            return View("FullView");
        }
```

And some SEO issues as mentioned.